# Mysql REGEX for detecting long lines

Tags: mysql, regex, formatting

I have some records in my database that looks like that :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.......
<PRE>
one short line
an other short line
a very long line I want to detect with more than 80 caracterssssssssssssssssss
again some short lines
</PRE>
Nullam tristique nisl eu lacus fringilla porta. ........
```

I would like to detect long lines (>80 caracters) inside the `PRE` tags and then I will edit them manually.

I tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 
    REGEXP "<PRE>.*[\n\r]+[^\n\r]{80,}[\n\r]+.*</PRE>"
```

but it's returning records where there is no long lines.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: What happens if you replace all of the ` \ ` in the regex string with ` \\ `?

Comment: @cdhowie : not working, it matches also some short lines...

Comment: Since you're going to edit manually, why not dump the table and process it with more familiar tools? (I know, there are lots of reasons, but it's a thought...)

Comment: @grossvogel : indeed why not ? Well there is a lot of data and only a few of them will have this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\n\r]{80,}` isn't necessarily matching a line in the PRE element where it starts searching.  The `.*` could be matching the closing `</PRE>` tag and beyond, so the long line could be in another PRE element if there is one, or even in the text between PRE elements.

I don't think there's a bullet-proof way to do what you want in MySQL, but you could try this:

```
<PRE>[^<]*[\n\r][^\n\r<]{80,}
```

You've said there won't be any other markup inside the PRE element, so any angle bracket in its content should be in the form of an escape sequence like `&lt;`, and the first `<` the regex encounters should be one in the `</PRE>` tag.

It's a hack, but without lookaheads, this is the only way I can think of to constrain the match to within the same PRE element.  To do this job *right*, you should do it outside MySQL altogether.

Comment: I'm think I'm goind to do it outside of Mysql, with a big php loop. I wanted to avoid that but...

Answer (score 1):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*` so the regex parser isn't greedy

Comment: I'm getting "Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Answer (score 0):

If there could be more then one `<PRE>` block, you expression can swallow space in between them. Change `[^\n\r]{80,}` to `[^\n\r]{80,}?`.

Comment: I'm getting "Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Comment: Well, I guess then the expression language is different then in Perl. :(

Comment: That page (well, its English version) doesn't mention non-greedy matches at all, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<PRE>\s*[^\n\r]{80,}.*?</PRE>
```

Note that this assumes that the `</PRE>` tag never comes on the same line as the content. (If it did, you could consume 74 characters of 'long line' followed by the closing tag, and then you would consume a lot of content up until the next closing tag.)

Comment: I'm updated question because it wasn't very clear. I have multiple lines (source code) but I want to detect the codes where some on the lines are too longs.

Comment: @LoïcFévrier If your content is allowed to have any other markup (legal in HTML) I *think* that you will need to do a subselect - first select from `<pre>.+?</pre>` and then select the >80 lines in those.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of stuff can be matched by `[^\n\r]{80,}`, including `</PRE>blah blah<PRE>`, so there might be false positives again.

Comment: @cababunga : we can assume that there won't be two PRE on the same line.

Comment: @Phrogz The content will be source code : c++, php...not for sure no html

Comment: I don't do PHP myself, but I sure seen PHP code that has lots of embedded HTML.

Comment: @cababunga : it's for some king of algorithmic course so in fact there will be not html inside. More often it will be  :c++, java, pascal, ObjectiveC...